# Script won't work unless there's: ></script> after the /head

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still new to all this, and very touchy-feely about it all, but I think I'm getting the hang of it.

I'm trying to use pageslide.js jquery script, and I've managed to make it work, but only if there's a;

```
></script>
```

after the /head tag, which leaves a > at the top of the page. I guess I could hide it, but I'd rather work out why. Any clues where to look?

The head currently looks like this;

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
></script>

<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script><script src="jquery.pageslide.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.pageslide.css">

<body>
yada yada
```

If I take this away, the script stops working. Just confused!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You've probably got some invalid markup, like a rogue `<`, floating around somewhere. How about an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: your html is all f up man... there isn't suppose to be any markup between `<head></head>` and `<body></body>`

Comment: @user161722: That's what the whole question is about!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should keep your script tag inside your `<head></head>` tag or into your `<body></body>` tag.

You have put it between them.

This should be the boilerplate code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    yada yada
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this and tell me if it works:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script><script src="jquery.pageslide.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.pageslide.css">

</head>
<body>
yada yada
```

You should close `</head>` before the `<body>`

Answer (score 0):

the reason it does that is because the browser sorts tags that aren't explicitly inside a `<head>` or `<body>` to their appropriate position.

so if you have `<link>` and `<script>` tags between `</head>` `<body>` the browser will then put those tags inside of the `<head>` tag because their generally associated with the head tag.

but when you put the `>` in front of that, the browse now will stop putting tags in the `<head>` and instead put everything else in the `<body>` because `>` is just plain text, and plain text belongs in the body along with other html tags like `<div>`,`<span>`, etc.. that being the case you can put any text in the place of `>` and it will still 'work'(in your case).

this is very cool because you can leave out the `<html>`,`<body>` and `<head>` tags out completely thus:

this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
></script>

<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script><script src="jquery.pageslide.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.pageslide.css">

<body>
yada yada
```

is the same as

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<div></div>

<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script><script src="jquery.pageslide.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.pageslide.css">

yada yada
```

in short terms:
  adding `></script>` is the difference in the browser putting

```
  <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script><script src="jquery.pageslide.js">   </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.pageslide.css">
```

in the `<body>` or in the `<head>` tag

Comment: Ok, so reading all the answers and trying all of them (thank you all so much!!! Honestly!! :D), none of them seemed to work, which just made me scratch my head harder. I know it's a rookie mistake, which is what was annoying..

However, based on something Jay said (thanks again!), I tried moving the script tags inside the <body> tag, instead of the <head>, and it seems to work! Don't totally get whey, and all those answers (reading them now) were what I was looking for, but, yeah, it works the (wrong?) way!!

Big help tho, cheers!!